# accept="application/pdf" not working in mozilla browser

Tags: html, mozilla

I have to restrict user to upload only PDF files so i used accept attribute but it is not working in Mozilla browser and in all browser it is working fine. I know we can check it through java script or server side but i have to restrict the dialog box so that it will not show other files.

Please guide to help this, or provide me other solution which work in Mozilla also.

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be a known issue with FF: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=826176